# different checksum of original file and copied file

Tags: rhel, checksum, hashsum

I am running a script that copy a file from one location to other. In script I am calculating MD5sum using below command of original file and copied file and they are different:

```
echo -n "file" | md5sum
```

How come a same file have different MD5sum? Does copy command change something in Linux?
I have also checked checksum using `cksum filename` and it is also coming different.

Comment: `echo -n "file" | md5sum` calculates the sum of the string "file", you want `cat file | md5sum` or just `md5sum file`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> echo -n "file" | md5sum
> ```

You are not calculating the checksum of the *file*, but of the *filename*. It is probably different because you are using two different paths (`echo -n "/old/path/to/file" | md5sum` vs. `echo -n "/new/path/to/file" | md5sum`).

To calculate the md5sum of the *file*, use this command:

```
md5sum file
```

Comment: Thanks Martin.I have one more confusion that if a file is zipped into tgz then untar it. Then the both original and untar file will also have the same checksum or different?

Comment: If you compare the original file with the zipped tgz file - no, they will not have the same checksum. If you extract the tgz file and compare the extracted file with the original file - yes, they must have the same checksum.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/crcsum/?source=directory
which provides a cp and mv extended with checksum calculation & verification

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.